# Use Powershell to perform summary and consolidation like awk

Tags: powershell

I have an awk script that generates a summary of several columns based on specific rules. I need to achieve the same on a Windows server running PowerShell v4.

```
TxnStat|Station|Ccy|Fcy|Lcy|Date
NEW|BRANCH|USD|1000|10|20190410
NEW|ATM|GBP|100|25|20190410
NEW|ATM|GBP|50|10|20190410
NEW|BRANCH|GBP|200|47|20190410
NEW|BRANCH|USD|250|20|20190410
```

The idea is to group all records that share the same Station (field 2) and Currency (field 3) and then:

1. Calculate the sum of Fcy Amount for the group (field 4)
2. Calculate sum of LCY amount for the group (field 5)
3. Calculate field 5/field 4 (i.e. exch rate)
4. Get the average exch rate (exch/no. of items per group)

The result I'm looking for is this. I am stripping out the header:

```
NEW,BRANCH,USD,30.00,1250.00,0.02,0.01,20190410
NEW,ATM,GBP,35.00,150.00,0.23,0.12,20190410
NEW,BRANCH,GBP,47.00,200.00,0.23,0.23,20190410
```

I used the awk script below to achieve this:

```
tail -n+2 TEST.CSV | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=","}
{fcy_tot[$2$3]+=$4;num_recs[$2$3]+=1;
lcy_tot[$2$3]+=$5;str_1[$2$3]=$1OFS$2OFS$3;
dt_str[$2$3]=$6;}
END
{for (i in fcy_tot)
{exch=lcy_tot[i]/fcy_tot[i];
avg_rate=exch/num_recs[i];
printf "%s %.2,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%s\n",
str_1[i],lcy_tot[i],fcy_tot[i],exch,avg_rate,dt_str[i]}}'
```

It's a one-liner but I've broken it here for clarity.

**What have I done so far?**

I did some Googling and landed on the `group-object` function but I was only able to find the sum on one field using the `measure -sum` command. I need guidance on how to create custom calculations on multiple specific fields.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? It matters, because `Measure-Object` in PowerShell 6 (PowerShell Core) supports a more extensive set of capabilities than previous versions did, including being able to specify multiple fields for calculations, and provision of a scriptblock for calculations.  See [Microsoft Docs on `Measure-Object` for PS6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Also, you don't need to convert the file from being delimited with `|` to being delimited with `,`; PowerShell's `Import-CSV` allows you to specify a `-Delimiter` parameter since PS4.

Comment: I'm using PowerShell v4 on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input file is input.txt in the above format,

this script ( could also be formatted as a one liner) :

```
Import-Csv .\input.txt -Delim '|'|Group-Object Station,Ccy | ForEach-object {
    $Fcy,$Lcy = ($_.Group|Measure-Object Fcy,lcy -Sum).Sum
    $ExchRate = $Lcy / $Fcy
    $AvgExchR = $ExchRate / $_.Count
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TxnStat = $_.Group[0].TxnStat
        Station = $_.Group[0].Station
        Ccy     = $_.Group[0].Ccy  
        Fcy     = $Fcy.ToString('0.00')
        Lcy     = $Lcy.ToString('0.00')
        ExchRate= $ExchRate.ToString('0.00')
        AvgExchR= $AvgExchR.ToString('0.00')
        Date    = $_.Group[0].Date
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize # Format-Object just to visualize
```

yields:

```
TxnStat Station Ccy Fcy      Lcy   ExchRate AvgExchR Date
------- ------- --- ---      ---   -------- -------- ----
NEW     BRANCH  USD 1250.00  30.00 0.02     0.01     20190410
NEW     ATM     GBP 150.00   35.00 0.23     0.12     20190410
NEW     BRANCH  GBP 200.00   47.00 0.24     0.24     20190410
```

Looks like you swapped Fcy,Lcy in you sample output.

To output as a csv without header replace the `Format-Table` with

```
| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content output.csv
```

But `Export-Csv`/`ConvertTo-Csv` double quote all fields

```
"NEW","BRANCH","USD","1250.00","30.00","0.02","0.01","20190410"
"NEW","ATM","GBP","150.00","35.00","0.23","0.12","20190410"
"NEW","BRANCH","GBP","200.00","47.00","0.24","0.24","20190410"
```

That could also be dealt with, with a bit effort.

I didn't check explicitly if I used post PSv4 commands.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\10\SU_1423881.ps1

$Output = Import-Csv .\input.txt -Delim '|' | Group-Object Station,Ccy | ForEach-object {
    $Fcy,$Lcy = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Fcy,lcy -Sum).Sum
    $Prod = [Double] 0; ($_.Group|ForEach-Object{$Prod+=[Double]$_.Fcy*$_.Lcy})
    $ExchRate = $Lcy / $Fcy
    $AvgExchR = $ExchRate / $_.Count
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TxnStat = $_.Group[0].TxnStat
        Station = $_.Group[0].Station
        Ccy     = $_.Group[0].Ccy
        Fcy     = $Fcy.ToString('0.00')
        Lcy     = $Lcy.ToString('0.00')
        ExchRate= $ExchRate.ToString('0.00')
        AvgExchR= $AvgExchR.ToString('0.00')
        AvgWeigh= ($Prod / $Fcy).ToString('0.00')
        Date    = $_.Group[0].Date
    }
}
$Output | Format-Table -AutoSize
#$Output | ConvertTo-Csv -Not | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content output.csv
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SU_1423881.ps1

TxnStat Station Ccy Fcy     Lcy   ExchRate AvgExchR AvgWeigh Date
------- ------- --- ---     ---   -------- -------- -------- ----
NEW     BRANCH  USD 1250,00 30,00 0,02     0,01     12,00    20190410
NEW     ATM     GBP 150,00  35,00 0,23     0,12     20,00    20190410
NEW     BRANCH  GBP 200,00  47,00 0,24     0,24     47,00    20190410
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely more elegant than what I'd come up with.

I got a way to deal with the quotes thanks to this [link] (http://www.sqlmovers.com/removing-quotes-from-csv-created-by-powershell/)

Is there a way to calculate a weighted average as opposed to 'normal' average'?

The formula has been given as:
`sum((Lcy*Fcy))/sum(Fcy)`
So the ` Lcy*Fcy` should be done at individual row level to create a group sum. 

The group sum of the  `Lcy * Fcy` is divided by the group sum of Fcy. Like this:

` lcyfcy[$2$3]+=($4*$5);fcy_tot[$2$3]+=$4;
{avgexch=lcyfcy[i]/fcy_tot[i]; `

Comment: Let me see if I got that right the sum of the products of Fcy*Lcy (per row in the group) divided by the sum of sum of Fcy , I'll post an edit in a minute.

Comment: the sum is **row in the file** not row in the group:
So for each row we need to get the products of Fcy * Lcy before grouping them. I think an additional field is required to hold the value of Fcy * Lcy on the original file. 
Then use measure-object sum to divide the 2 sums.

Comment: I disagree, a sum per file would intermix currencys.

Comment: The consolidation is also per currency so it will not intermix the currencies. 
I have solved it by adding an extra field in the csv:
` Import-Csv .\text.txt -Delimiter "|" | Select-Object *,@{Name='LcyFcy';Expression={[long]$_.Lcy*[long]$_.Fcy}} `

The result of this is then piped to the script from LotPings